# Spring : Cannot infer type arguments for ResponseEntity<>

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, rest

This is my first time using Spring with mongodb and I am creating a REST API to get items based on who created them  . With my code however I get the error `"Cannot infer type arguments for ResponseEntity<>"` and I do not understand why .

My code :

Memory.java (single item)

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="Memories")
public class Memory {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String message;
    private String title;

    public Memory() {
        
    }
    
    public Memory(String creator , String title  ) {
        this.title = title;
        this.creator=creator;
    }
    

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
        
    public void setCreator(String creator ) {
        this.creator=creator;
    }

 

    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    
    }

     public void  setTitle(String title){
      this.title=title;
     }

    public String getTitle(){
      return title;    
    }

    }
```

MemoryRepository.java (interface)

```
public interface MemoryRepository extends MongoRepository<Memory,String>{

  List<Memory> findByCreator(String creator);
}
```

MemoryController.java (REST API )

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MemoryController {

    @Autowired
    MemoryRepository memoryRepo;
  
    //RETURNS MEMORIES BY CREATOR 
    @GetMapping("/memories/creator={creator}")
    public ResponseEntity<Memory> findByCreator(@PathVariable("creator") String creator){
        
        try {
            List<Memory>  memoriesFound = memoryRepo.findByCreator(creator);
            if(memoriesFound.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }else {
                //THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I GET THE ABOVE ERROR 
                return new ResponseEntity<>(memoriesFound,HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

I would appreciate your help with this . I looked at the docs of `ResponseEntity` but still no idea .

Comment: Your method is declared with a return type of `ResponseEntity<Memory>`. What are you trying to return at that line?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am trying to return all memories with the same creator field

Comment: Specifically, what would be the parameterization of `ResponseEntity` in `new ResponseEntity<>(memoriesFound,HttpStatus.OK);`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just found the error .  I should return ResponseEntity<List<Memory>> . Now I have no error but I get empty response

Comment: Hello Greek team :) . You have located correctly the error. Now you probably see the NoContent response which should be empty anyways

Comment: @Boug well why ?

Comment: @vasilis123 NoContent response does not have a body.

Comment: @Boug Yeah I should get the memories json . It shouldnt be empty

Comment: your code goes into `return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);` as the memories is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230470/discussion-between-vasilis-123-and-boug).